# Rsyslog: relay messages from UDP input only

Tags: multithreading, queue, message-queue, worker, rsyslog

Considering a docker container which receives logs on UDP and forwards to a central logging server using TLS, I was wondering if I could be satisfied with one queue or if I needed several.

Indeed, knowing that I won't be doing anything else than sending the logs to the collector, I don't really understand the need for several queues. Surely they make sense if other actions exist such as writing logs on files or duplicate outputs for failover, but **what if forwarding is the only task**? Wouldn't it be enough to have the main queue and the "send to collector" action in direct queue mode (i.e. no queue)? If the central server goes down (or during network outage) then logs will simply be re-enqueued to the main message queue ?

For example in this scenario below the `Action Q` makes total sense, but if we discard logging on `/var/log/messages` wouldn't `Action Q` be useless ? It's not only useless but also slows down the forwarding, right?

[image]

Comment: SO is a site to ask questions about programming. This question isn't programming related at all and would therefore be better of on another SE site like [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or the [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). Over there I'll happily answer your question.

Comment: It seems I can't tag you but I created a post on SU: https://superuser.com/questions/1734107/rsyslog-relay-messages-from-udp-input-only